# Why does Int(Float(Int.max)) give me an error?

Tags: swift, floating-point, type-conversion

I observed something really strange. If you run this code in Swift:

```
Int(Float(Int.max))
```

It crashes with the error message:

> fatal error: Float value cannot be converted to Int because the result would be greater than Int.max

This is really counter-intuitive, so I expanded the expression into 3 lines and tried to see what happens in each step in a playground:

```
let a = Int.max
let b = Float(a)
let c = Int(b)
```

It crashes with the same message. This time, I see that `a` is 9223372036854775807 and `b` is 9.223372e+18. It is obvious that `a` is greater than `b` by 36854775807. I also understand that floating points are inaccurate, so I expected something less than `Int.max`, with the last few digits being 0.

I also tried this with `Double`, it crashes too.

Then I thought, maybe this is just how floating point numbers behave, so I tested the same thing in Java:

```
long a = Long.MAX_VALUE;
float b = (float)a;
long c = (long)b;
System.out.println(c);
```

It prints the expected 9223372036854775807!

What is wrong with swift?

Comment: Java simply truncates in the Double/Float to long conversion, e.g. `(long)(1.0E100)` evaluates to 9223372036854775807 as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There aren't enough bits in the mantissa of a `Double` or `Float` to accurately represent `19` significant digits, so you are getting a rounded result.

If you print the `Float` using `String(format:)` you can see a more accurate representation of the value of the `Float`:

```
let a = Int.max
print(a)                          // 9223372036854775807
let b = Float(a)
print(String(format: "%.1f", b))  // 9223372036854775808.0
```

So the value represented by the `Float` is `1` larger than `Int.max`.

---

Many values will be converted to the same `Float` value.  The question becomes, how much would you have to reduce `Int.max` before it results in a different `Double` or `Float` value.

Starting with `Double`:

```
var y = Int.max

while Double(y) == Double(Int.max) {
    y -= 1
}

print(Int.max - y)  // 512
```

So with `Double`, the last `512` `Int`s all convert to the same `Double`.

`Float` has fewer bits to represent the value, so there are more values that all map to the same `Float`.  Switching to `- 1000` so that it runs in reasonable time:

```
var y = Int.max

while Float(y) == Float(Int.max) {
    y -= 1000
}

print(Int.max - y)  // 274877907000
```

So, your expectation that a `Float` could accurately represent a specific `Int` was misplaced.

---

Follow up question from the comments:

> If float does not have enough bits to represent Int.max, how is it
>   able to represent a number one larger than that?

Floating point numbers are represented as two parts: mantissa and exponent.  The mantissa represents the significant digits (in binary) and the exponent represents the power of 2.  As a result, a floating point number can accurately express an even power of 2 by having a mantissa of 1 with an exponent that represents the power.

Numbers that are not even powers of 2 may have a binary pattern that contains more digits than can be represented in the mantissa.  This is the case for `Int.max` (which is 2^63 - 1) because in binary that is `111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` (63 1's).  A `Float` which is 32 bits cannot store a mantissa which is 63 bits, so it has to be rounded or truncated.  In the case of `Int.max`, rounding up by 1 results in the value
`1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`.  Starting from the left, there is only 1 significant bit to be represented by the mantissa (the trailing `0`'s come for free), so this number is a mantissa of `1` and an exponent of `64`.

See @MartinR's answer for an explanation of what Java is doing.

Comment: If float does not have enough bits to represent `Int.max`, how is it able to represent a number one larger than that?

Comment: @Sweeper, that's a great question.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Sweeper It can simply store it with a mantissa of 1, and an exponent of 63 – so 1 * 2^63. However the bit pattern of 2^63 - 1 (`Int64.max`) is 63 repeated 1s, so needs to be rounded to be stored (as `Float` is only 32 bits long).

Answer (score 1):

Swift and Java behave differently when converting a "too large" floating point
number to an integer. Java truncates any floating point value
larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE = 2^63-1`:

```
long c = (long)(1.0E+30f);
System.out.println(c);
// 9223372036854775807
```

Swift expects that the value is in the range of `Int`, and aborts
with a runtime exception otherwise:

```
/// Creates a new instance by rounding the given floating-point value toward
/// zero.
///
/// - Parameter other: A floating-point value. When `other` is rounded toward
///   zero, the result must be within the range `Int.min...Int.max`.
public init(_ value: Float)
```

Example:

```
let c = Int(Float(1.0E30))
print(c)
// fatal error: Float value cannot be converted to Int because the result would be greater than Int.max
```

The same happens with your value `Float(Int.max)`, which is the
floating point representable value *closest* to `Int.max` and happens
to be larger than `Int.max`.