# Foundation: Why Int64.max and Double(Int64.max) prints 2 entire different value in Swift iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, foundation

Here is my Swift Code

```
print("\(Int64.max)")
print("\(Double(Int64.max))")
```

It produce following output

> 9223372036854775807
>
> 9.223372036854776e+18

Why the both value is entire different
9.223372036854776e+18 - 9223372036854775807 = 193    FYI

Comment: They are the same. One just uses scientific notation.

Comment: I wouldn't say they are "entirely" different. They are pretty close, aren't they?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706635/why-does-intfloatint-max-give-me-an-error) answer your question?

Comment: Nope they are different ... the difference is 193 ....  9.223372036854776e+18 - 9223372036854775807 = 193 FYI

Comment: @Sweeper Yes ... it does answer the question ... but i am still bit confused

Answer (score 5):

The value of `Double` you are seeing in the output is only an approximation to some number of significant figures. We can see more significant figures by `String(format:)`

```
print(String(format: "%.1f", Double(Int64.max)))
```

This prints:

```
9223372036854775808.0
```

So actually, the difference is not as big as what you claimed it was (193). It's just a difference of 1.

> Why is there a difference?

`Double` stores value using a floating point representation. It can represent a wide range of numbers, but not every number in that range. `Double` uses 53 bits of mantissa, 1 sign bit and 11 bits to store the exponent. The mantissa represents the significant digits of the number, and the exponent tells you where to put the decimal point. Everything on one side of the decimal point represents positive powers of 2 and everything on the other side represent negative powers of 2. For example:

```
0.1010000    0010
  mantissa    exponent
```

The exponent says to move the decimal point to the right 3 times, so the mantissa becomes `010.10000`. The `1` on the left represents 2, and the 1 on the right represents a half (2^-1), so this floating point number represents the number 2.5

To represent `Int64.max` (2^63-1), you need 63 bits of mantissa to all be 1s and the value in the exponent to be 63. But `Double` does not have that many bits of mantissa! So it can only approximate. `Int64.max + 1` is actually representable by a `Double`, because it is equal to `2^63`. You just need one `1` followed by 52 `0`s in the mantissa and the exponent can store `64`. And that's what `Double` did.

Comment: Nice explanation. If you want more information about floating point representation. You can read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754